# Firefox Selenium (python) won't open a WebRTC Stream

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webrtc, selenium-firefoxdriver

So, I'm trying to open a WebRTC stream with Firefox webdriver. 
It works just fine on Chrome, but the stream won't start playing on Firefox. The page loads, but no audio/video.

Firefox can play the stream just fine on my normal user profile, but won't work from Selenium.

This is the only difference in the code:

```
def newFirefoxWindow(self):
        print("Opening a firefox window")
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.set_preference("media.navigator.permission.disabled", 1)
        profile.set_preference("permissions.default.microphone", 1)
        profile.set_preference("permissions.default.camera", 1)
        profile.set_preference("media.block-autoplay-until-in-foreground", False)
        profile.set_preference("media.autoplay.default", 1)
        profile.set_preference("media.autoplay.allow-muted", False)
        profile.set_preference("plugin.state.flash", 1)
        profile.set_preference("webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs", True)
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

        return driver
```

This works in Chrome:

```
def newChromeWindow(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument("--test-type")
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
            }
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        return driver
```

Any suggestions? Is there a Firefox setting that I am missing?

Comment: Still won't work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow media autoplay in Firefox by setting `media.autoplay.default` to `0`. Here are my working Firefox capabilities in WebdriverIO:

```
'firefox': {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        prefs: {
            "media.navigator.streams.fake": true,
            "media.navigator.permission.disabled": true,
            "media.autoplay.default": 0,
            "media.volume_scale": "0.0"
        }
    }
}
```